# SQL parsing delimited data in one column out to two other columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an existing table in MySQL with data synchronized data that ends up looking something like this:

```
id      client      notes           id1         id2
------- ---------   ------------    ----------  ----------
1       a           cat dog|3|90
2       b
3       c           |80|12
4       d           dog only
5       e
6       f           |34|40
```

I want it to look like this:

```
id      client      notes           id1         id2
------- ---------   ------------    ----------  ----------
1       a           cat dog|3|90    3           90
2       b
3       c           |80|12          80          12  
4       d           dog only
5       e
6       f           |34|40          34          40
```

What is the SQL logic to accomplish this? The delimiter will always be two pipes. That is I want a statement that I can apply to the table in phpMyAdmin to clean up the sync and separate out the id's properly.

Comment: **DON'T STORE DELIMITED DATA IN COLUMNS!**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substring_index()`:

```
select id, client, notes,
       substring_index(substring_index(notes, '|', 2), '|', -1) as id1,
       substring_index(notes, '|', -1) as id2
from . . .;
```

Comment: Thank you.  The query works great.  As an update statement I am having difficulty: UPDATE `table`  SET  `id1`  = SUBSTRING_INDEX(`notes`, '|', -1), 
`id2` = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`notes`, '|', 2), '|', -1)
this generates " Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails".  What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @CraigTucker . . . Clearly, you have some sort of foreign key relationship that does not like the values being inserted in the columns.

Comment: Ok, I added SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; and all went well.  Thank you.

Comment: @CraigTucker: Aaand now, you no longer have a database, you have a *file*.